# Private domains for Sender Profiles and IP warm-up

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package, ip

I have a Salesforce Marketing Cloud question on the SAP registration and the private domains used for Sender Profiles, specifically when it comes to IP warm-up.

1. If you already have existing private domains used for email sends, can the DNS of these simply point to the exacttarget servers so they can warm up the IP address (associated with the SAP) when used in the Sender Profiles? Either way, my understanding is that these existing private domains need to be registered with the SAP for them to be usable for Sender Profiles.
2. Alternatively, if we register new private sub-domains for the Sender Profiles with the SAP, then I assume Salesforce will manage the SPF and DKIM. Then would these also warm-up the IP address (associated with the SAP) when sending emails under the Sender Profiles?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little confusing, but let me see if I have understood it correctly.

Private Domains don't come with their own IP address. You normally will have one SAP for your Business Unit allocated one IP address.

If you want to either have multiple sender domains, you can purchase additional Private Domains, but they will all use the IP address of the SAP for the given Business Unit. When you create a new private domain, you will normally delegate its DNS records to the name servers of Salesforce/Exacttarget, and they will manage the settings accordingly.

If you have already warmed up your IP address by sending emails on your SAP domain, you will normally not need to do any IP warmup specifically for the new Private Domain.

Answer (score 3):

question number one is what the existing Private Domains are used for. See below.

If you have a "sendout" Private Domain, the Delivery profile - not the sender profile - manages which IP you warm up. So you are free to combine domain and IP, although keeping the setup stable during the warm up is recommended.

The following is largely sourced directly from Salesforce documents (which explains the "we" in the text) and should help answer your questions.

The relevant part is the second half (I included a divider to mark the spot), but I included the entire text so nothing is taken out of context:

"
What is the difference between a Private Domain that is included with the Sender Authentication Package (SAP), versus a Private Domain that is purchased separately?

A Sender Authentication Package (SAP) is a "branding" tool.  A Sender Authentication Private Domain includes link-wrapping (i.e. links, images, and anything else that would normally reflect Marketing Cloud will reflect the chosen Sender Authentication domain instead when you hover). The domain is also authenticated with SPF/Sender ID and DKIM/Domain Keys.

SAP is a bundle of products (Private Domain, Dedicated IP, RMM and URL wrapping)

URL wrapping (commonly referred to as “account branding” is only available through a full SAP configuration)

There is a limit of 1 SAP per MID/account which means an account can only be “branded” with 1 domain (if a client needs to have unique branding for multiple lines of business then they’ll need multiple MIDs with an SAP per MID)

The SAP SKU (==product) cannot be broken into parts (i.e. we’re unable to simply pull the Private Domain out of a purchased SAP SKU)

---

A private domain is used as an authentication tool.  A Private Domain that is purchased separately for sending is an authenticated domain for use in the FROM address only.

It is set up either via a User or Sender Profile, and this type of Private Domain DOES NOT include link or image-wrapping. It has an MX record, SPF/Sender ID and DKIM/Domain Keys.

While a single account MID can support only 1 SAP for branding purposes, there can be multiple domains in an account.

Private Domain is a single domain configuration (as opposed to a bundle of products). A single SKU (purchased product) can be used for 1 of 3 options (1 Private Domain - 1 option):

Private Domain for sending – authenticated for sending mail (we’ll sign the domain with SPF and DKIM for use in a From address) (unlimited number of Private Domains for sending per MID – one Private Domain SKU for each domain)

Private Domain for Landing Pages – the domain chosen can be used to uniquely brand landing page URLs in a client account (limit 1 landing page domain per MID)

Private Domain for Cloud Pages – the domain chosen can be used to uniquely brand Cloud Page URLs in a client account (unlimited number of Private Domains for Cloud Pages per MID – one Private Domain SKU for each domain)

The DNS records needed for each of these options varies which means a single Private Domain SKU cannot be used for both Landing Pages and Cloud Pages. (e.g. if your Landing Pages domain is pages.domain.com, the Cloud Pages domain cannot be pages.domain.com - they must be different)
"

hope this helps!